# HTML lists (<li>) vertical on page, changing to inline

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a list of anchors that is displayed in a vertical list.  Upon clicking a certain one I am opening a partial view with another list of li items, but specifically changed to be inline.  Only problem is that when the partial view is displayed the main view list of items changes to inline as well.  Is there anyway around this?

Main page portion;

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="return OpenAdminPage('user');" >User Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="return OpenAdminPage('role');" >Role Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="return OpenAdminPage('type');" >Item Type Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="return OpenAdminPage('tran');" >Transaction Type Maintenance</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" onclick="return OpenAdminPage('inven');" >Inventory Control Maintenance</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

partial view:

```
 <ul>
 @if (Model != null)
 {
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.InventoryRoleCode)
    for (var rolcnt = 0; rolcnt < Model.Roles.Count(); rolcnt++)
    {
        <li style="color:black;font-size:x-small">
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Roles[rolcnt].ItemTypeCode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Roles[rolcnt].ItemTypeCode)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxForWithTitle(x=>x.Roles[rolcnt].Included)
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
   <style>
         ul li
     {
           display: inline-block;
        }
       </style>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Add a class to the partials ul `<ul class="child-ul">` and then update the CSS to be `.child-ul li {}`. Your CSS declaration is also targeting the original ul li list once the partial loads in.

You probably do not want to load in that CSS in the partial over and over again either everytime an li is clicked but instead include it in the 'main page portion'.

Comment: You have, for what I could understand, a nested list inside a list?
If that's the point, you can add CSS that nested li have inline style and the parent one a block one